# LESS file watching

Tags: less

I know most LESS software includes file watchers that track changes to .less files and automatically recompile/create the .css code.  I work in a team where unfortunately, several folks tweak the .css as the develop code, and usually forget to tell the UIX developer (me).  My first indicator is usually them asking me why certain style elements are missing, and they know they inserted the code correctly just yesterday...

Is there any LESS software that also watches css files and when updated, will automatically update the source .less file?  I have looked around at several (WinLess, Prepos, Crunch) but can't find anything.

Any help/recommendations greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have one advice. Don't try to implement a workaround of the lack of knowledge in some team members. You should educate them (example: extend the on-boarding documentation) and exclude `css` files from the source control. I think most of the developers are smart enough to not modify files in `generated` directory or which are excluded from SCM.

Comment: yes , what is your platform ? win ?

Comment: write this message to top of your files /**  File Generated Automatically */

Comment: and also you can use Version Controls

Comment: @agabrys - I appreciate (and agree with) what you are saying, but that is an element of the problem I can't control at the moment.  I will see what I can do about excluding the css and less files from source control.

Comment: @hossein sedighian - Windows, using VS2017 TFS.  Version controlling helps, but has not been the total answer, since some of the code is flagged in the merge process, and they choose their own code over the server code.  I like the message suggestion.

Comment: you can easily install a watcher on client sides with report changes to your server

Comment: and commit edit mannualy